# Preparing walls for plastering

Tags: repair, walls

Hi I'm pulling down wallpaper in front room as I want to paint it but I've found that the old plastering is coming off with the wallpaper, and on last wall I've found they painted under it as well! Lucky I've spoken to my housing association and they are responsible for structure but not decorating so they said there sending a plasterer to do the walls. My question is do I need to get all the paint off in preparation for them to do the walls? The woodchip wallpaper was a breeze compared to this paint! Any advice would be much appreciated.

Oh yeah I did ask my housing association but the have no clue they use contractors I guess.

Answer (score 1):

*My housing association said **they are responsible for structure** but not decorating so they said **they're sending a plasterer to do the walls.***

Then you do nothing except more your stuff out of the way, if even that.

Comment: The contractors will do whatever preparation they need to. Don't worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

My advice is not to remove anything if a skip trowled finish wall would appeal to you, which is desirable in southern regions, and is something you could do yourself.

If you're looking for a smooth finish and the walls are messed up, you can mount 1/4" Sheetrock on the walls, tape spackle, prime and paint.